# Are there Tai languages (or Tai-Kadai) which have a voiced velar stop phoneme?

Tags: phonology, phonemes, voicing, velar

Thai and Lao each have three series of stops, unvoiced unaspirated, aspirated, and voiced.

For labials and alveolars, all three exist, but for velars there is no voiced stop.

Is this the case for all Tai languages? For all Tai-Kadai languages?

Comment: BTW, Wikipedia has a fairly [detailed insight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_language#Old_Thai) on this topic, suggesting that Old Thai had full range of voiced stops.

Comment: @bytebuster: Ah thanks. I had terrible trouble getting Wikipedia or Wiktionary pages to load earlier and couldn't find info elsewhere just by Googling.